# Calculate change in value by Date and ID in python

Tags: python, datetime, return-value, timedelta

I have a dataframe that contains three columns: IDs, date (always month end) and a value for a given ID at a given date. The values change over time and are unique to the IDs. How can I calculate the change in value for a given ID from one month to the next (both as a percent and absolute value)?

Here is sample data. I want to have a new column which would show that for ID 1850 the change from 2007-12-01 to 2008-01-01 is .0004 and so on for each ID for each month over month change. There are ~100k total rows and ~1000 different IDs

````
Date                ID       value_
2007-12-01 00:00:00 1850    -0.0496133979294919
2008-01-01 00:00:00 1850    -0.0500387131996307
2008-02-01 00:00:00 1850    -0.0492422215808407
2007-02-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0195919625346613
2007-03-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0194071594854936
2007-04-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.00949770507514844
2007-05-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.00611289851053481
2007-06-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.00966828278354329
2007-07-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.010420327834716
2007-08-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.00374361336176163
2007-09-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0217189168574824
2007-10-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0210927493134818
2007-11-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0208540558170204
2007-12-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0281891859572789
2008-01-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0342401666700859
2008-02-01 00:00:00 4022    -0.0345209140419046
2007-12-01 00:00:00 51667   -0.00457253924855003
2008-01-01 00:00:00 51667   -0.00613436134423086
2008-02-01 00:00:00 51667   -0.011212483689408
```)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the dataframe is sorted by ID and date.

Group by ID use diff() on the value column:

```
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['value_'].diff().fillna(0)
```